Is there a definite equation for the rate of sinking of a particle in a liquid?
Ive looked for over 3 hours and find no coherent answers and all different ones. I was wondering if someone could help me with that. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the particle is small enough, and the fluid is approximately at rest, you can solve your problem integrating the equation of motion
$$m \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = m \mathbf{g} + \mathbf{F}^{fluid} \ ,$$
i.e. the motion of a small particle under its own weight and the resistance due to the motion in a fluid. When the regime of motion is characterised by a small Reynolds number, the drag is well represented by Stokes' formula
$$\mathbf{F}^{fluid} = \mathbf{F}^{Stokes} = - 6 \pi \mu R \mathbf{v} \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{v} = \dot{\mathbf{r}}$ the velocity of the particle w.r.t. the surrounding fluid at rest.
If you want to solve for velocity, you need to solve an ODE with expression
$$m \dot{\mathbf{v}} + c \mathbf{v} = m \mathbf{g} \ ,$$
whose solution reads
$$\mathbf{v}(t) = \frac{m}{c}\mathbf{g} + k \hat{\mathbf{v}} e^{-\frac{c}{m}t}$$
with the constant $k$ to be determined with an initial condition. When the transient is over, the velocity is approximately
$$\bar{\mathbf{v}} = \frac{m}{c}\mathbf{g} \ .$$
For estimating the length of the transient, you can use the time constant of the 1st order equations, like the one governing the velocity.
